# software center problem

Tags: 12.04

I have read loads of posts about this but no solutions have worked I am new to linux this is my first install, my linux is ubuntu 12.04 lts, I cannot upgrade the upgrade has problems with my gfx on my old amilo pro. I get

```
   linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/52.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 148 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 169695 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic (from .../linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic_3.13.0-79.123~precise1_i386.deb) ...
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic_3.13.0-79.123~precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic_3.13.0-79.123~precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I cannot `sudo apt-get install -f` it does nothing
clean does not seem to do anything
`autoclean` does not seem to do anything either, I cannot remember all the things I tried. please be gentle :D

Answer (score 0):

THis error is shown because your processor Dosent support PEA.

> Physical Address Extension (PAE) is a feature found on almost all 32 bit processors produced after Pentium Pro, ie. younger than around 1995. Because PAE is close to being a standard it is now a requirement for Ubuntu: During installation the processor is prompted for the PAE flag, and only if present the process will carry on.

[For more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE)

The ways I could find to over come this issue are

1. Switch to  [xubuntu 12.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04/release/) / [lubuntu 12.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/)
2. Install ubuntu again from the netboot minimal ISO. [Guide for this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-install-ubuntu-1204-on-non-pae.html)
3. Download non-PEA release and lnstall [link](http://people.canonical.com/~diwic/12.04-nonpae/)(easiest)

Comment: it took me hours to get this installed I really do not fancy going to those lengths again, I can only install via usb drive but I know how to do that. is there really no other option?

Comment: I couldn't find any if u already have the bootable pendrive u can try the force PEA option will add that to the answer. Other than that i don't think so but it could be there.

Comment: Sorry but for  forcePEA also u will require to do the installation again

Comment: I did a force pae i had no other option because the comp would just freeze and not continue

Comment: You could have given the force pea flag while installation to avoid this.The best way to resolve this now will be to reinstall

Comment: I used a guide to get this installed that said for my processor I could use forcepae -- forcepae to get installed this worked I am on that computer now. the last time I attempted this I immediately upgraded and regreted it because the comp was running super slowly it was like an install of windows 7 on this (yeah I tried) too slow so this is as far as I am concerned my forst good install if I have to I hope the install goes faster next time earlier today I got zorin installed on my wife's laptop and it runs like a dream I am envious.

Comment: If your computer got slow I would recommend you to install xubuntu or some other lighter distro. Zorin have not heard of it.

Comment: thanks for the help but in answer to your question the build I have the now is running like a dream except the problem I have it is not lightning but it is fast.

Comment: one last question I am going to try lubuntu if all else fails do I need to forcepae I am assuming I won't

Comment: http://zorinos.com/

Comment: You won't have to will u are going to install a version <= lubuntu 12.04

Comment: yeah my usb installer had 12.04

Comment: then reffer this link: help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE